# Same ios gameCenterID Different devices

Tags: ios, firebase, authentication, game-center

hi I am using Firebase and have a specific issue that I would like to ask about. I discovered that when a user logs in with the same Game Center ID on two different devices, 1. os15.6, 2. os 13.1, the Firebase User UIDs are stored differently. Can Firebase User UIDs be created differently depending on the device or OS?”

It did not occur on OS 14 or higher, but it seems to have occurred on 13, so I am asking.

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to a new Game Center API being introduced in iOS 13.5 and FirebaseAuth using a different set of APIs for 13.5 and newer.

The number of devices running 13.4 or less is tiny, so this is unlikely to be a prioritized issue.

Code reference at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/FirebaseAuth/Sources/AuthProvider/GameCenter/FIRGameCenterAuthProvider.m#L57